# Getting domain name from a url using powershell?

Tags: powershell

Basically I have a huge csv of phishing links and I'm trying to trim off https://www. and anything after .com .edu etc. so basically the ideal ouput of the powershell script would be a long list of urls all of which look something like google.com or microsoft.com so far I have imported the csv but everything I have tried either doesn't work or leaves the www on the beggining. Any help would be great. The csv im using is this: http://data.phishtank.com/data/online-valid.csv

```
$urls = Import-Csv -Path .\online-valid.csv | select -ExpandProperty "url"
```

Comment: run this `[URI]'http://www.phishtank.com/phish_detail.php?phish_id=6429209'`  and you're half there. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below will take your CSV and do magic for you. Have a play around with `[Uri]`, it is very useful when parsing web links.

```
$csv = import-csv C:\temp\verified_online.csv

Foreach($Site in $csv) {
    $site | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Host" -Value $(([Uri]$Site.url).Host -replace '^www\.')
}

$csv | Export-Csv C:\temp\verified_online2.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Adjusted based on recommendation from Mklement0.

Answer (score 1):

A **concise and fast alternative** to [Drew's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60499364/45375) based on casting the URL strings directly to an *array* of `[uri]` ([`System.Uri`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Uri)) instances, and then trimming prefix `www.`, if present, from their `.Host` (server name) property:

```
([uri[]] (Import-Csv .\online-valid.csv).url).Host -replace '^www\.'
```

Note that the [`-replace` operator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40683667/45375) is regex-based, and regex `^www\.` makes sure what `www` is only replaced at the start (`^`) of the string, and only if followed by a *literal* `.` (`\.`), in which case this prefix is removed (replaced with the implied empty string); if no such prefix is present, the input string is passed through as-is.

The solution reads the entire CSV file into memory at once, for convenience and speed, and **outputs just the trimmed server names**, as an array of strings.